# Why does VB convert true into -1 not 1?

Tags: vba, vb.net, vb6

Most of the programming languages converts `false` into `0` and `true` into `1`. But VB6, Office VBA and VB.NET converts `true` into `-1`. Why does VB convert logical value like this?

Comment: Because that is what it is documented to do.

Comment: `true` is a non zero value. There is false (`0`) and non false (`<>0`).

Comment: Also VBA only supports signed integers. `-1` = `&hFFFFFFFF` ie all bits are set in the number. But as I said above true is a non zero number. The CPU tests if it is `0` or not `0`. The computer has to convert what you type to a number. It chooses the same number as the Windows API.